# Oracle sql error ora-01722 invalid number ora-02063 preceding line from

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, adodb

I ran a sql query in oracle sql developer and it works just fine but when I use a wrapper, in this case adodb in excel vba, to execute the same query I get an error. I suspect adodb is using a different version of oracle and the optimization is done differently.

The query I ran is:
`select (LATITUDE) from db where sin(LATITUDE) <= 45.0;`

I get the error:

ORA-01722: invalid number

ORA-02063: preceding line from db

If I change `sin(LATITUDE) <= 45.0` in query to:

`LATITUDE <= 45.0` (it doesn't work)

`LATITUDE <= '45.0'` (it works)

`sin(LATITUDE) <= '45.0'` (it doesn't work)

`to_number(sin(LATITUDE)) <= 45.0` (it doesn't work)

`sin(to_number(LATITUDE)) <= '45.0'` (it doesn't work)

I also tried casting LATITUDE to a float and that doesn't work either. The only instance where it runs is without the SIN and with the single quotes around the floating value on the right of the condition.

I am at a loss as to why I can't get the query to run without any errors even though it runs just fine in Oracle SQL Developer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you run it in SQL Developer, are you just getting the first page of values in the data grid? I'd expect you to see the same error if you retrieve all the rows in the result set (scroll to the bottom of the grid, or run as a script); at the moment you just aren't reaching the row(s) that have bad data. Is latitude stored as a number or as a string?

Comment: No. I get the entire in SQL Developer. But through ADODB, the query doesn't even run and produces the error.

Comment: That query doesn't make sense (quite apart from the data type and data problem that is the source of your actual error).  The `sin` of a number is, by definition, between -1 and 1.  Checking whether it is less than 45 doesn't make sense.  Perhaps you want rows where `latitude <= 45`?

Comment: One other possibility for the different behaviour that comes to mind; assuming `latitude` is a varchar2 column as (I think) we've been assuming: does it contain strings that are decimal values with a period, or a comma, or both? You could see the error in one session but not the other if the sessions get different `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` settings - in one session an implicit conversion of `'0,1'` would work while `'0.1'` errors, and vice versa in the other session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it appears that `LATITUDE` is stored as a number and some of the values are not numeric.

Perhaps a query like this will help you figure out the problem:

```
select latitude
from db
where translate(latitude, '-0123456789.a', 'a') is not null;
```

This is not a perfect test, but it often works.

EDIT:

A better method uses regular expressions:

```
select latitude
from db
where not regexp_like(latitutde, '^-?[[:digit:]]*[.]?[[:digit:]]*$')
```

Comment: Thanks that did help. There were some values that were returned after running this query. So I assumed that was the problem. But, I thought this query would fix the problem: select latitude from (select (LATITUDE) from irtt_meter_mv@cmomprd where translate(latitude, '-0123456789.a', 'a') is null) where sin(latitude) <= 2 ... this query still gives me the same error.

Comment: @sayan . . . You might have other malformed values, such as"-42-42".

Comment: Is there any other way around it that will filter out the non-numeric data or convert them to a number before the SIN operation?

Answer (score 0):

Following investigation in comments, this seems to be a difference in the NLS set-up between the direct SQL client and the ADODB connection. Because you are storing a number as a string (which is always a bad idea) and the number has a decimal separator, the different NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS settings are causing an error in one place but not the other.

Oracle uses that NLS setting when you an implicit conversion from a string to a number, or if you have an explicit `to_number()` call without a format mask. So in any environment one of these statements will work and the other will get an ORA-01722 error:

```
select to_number('0,1') from dual;
select to_number('0.1') from dual;
```

Which one fails depends on the NLS setting. You can use an explicit format mask to avoid this, and the third parameter to `to_number()` to say how to interpret it:

```
select to_number('0,1', '99D99999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''') from dual;
select to_number('0.1', '99D99999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''') from dual;
```

This is using the `D` decimal separator marker, which corresponds to the first character in the NLS override - notice that the period and comma switch between those two statements - and that NLS override has to be set to match your actual data. You also need to use an appropriate number digits before and after the decimal of course.

On the assumption you're dealing with [decimal degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) you should be able to use:

```
select to_number(latitude, '999D99999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''')
from irtt_meter_mv@cmomprd;
```

You only really need to two nines before the decimal for latitude, but you'll need three for longitude, so you might as well be consistent.

But you also need to do that explicit conversion everywhere you reference it, so for example:

```
select to_number(latitude, '999D99999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''')
from irtt_meter_mv@cmomprd;
where abs(to_number(latitude, '999D99999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''')) < 45;
```

This would be avoided if you were using the correct datatype in the first place. If you can't change the column type you could consider adding a virtual column that does that same conversion for you, or if that isn't allowed a view that changes the type.

---

An earlier answer gave a variation on Gordon Linoff's, but turns out to be a red herring.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am still getting the same error when using `'select latitude from db where case when not regexp_like(latitude, '^-?[[:digit:]]*[.]?[[:digit:]]*$') then sin(latitude) end <= 2`                                             or this query: `select latitude from db where case when translate(latitude, '-0123456789.a', 'a') is null then sin(latitude) end <= 2`.                       Note that I have just simplified the query so that its easier to debug and understand that this will return all the rows. The goal is to run the query without this error.

Comment: @sayan - can you clarify what the data type is for the `latitude` column? And if it's a string, what does `select to_number(latitude) from irtt_meter_mv@cmomprd` with no where clause at all do, from your SQL client and through ADODB?

Comment: I get the same error with that query. I am not sure what the datatype of latitude is. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: Query the all_tab_columns view. But it seems to be a string, which is what we've been assuming anyway. So next thing to check, if you can, is the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS value in both sessions.

Comment: @sayan - or to see if that is the issue, try `select to_number(latitude, '999D99999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') from irtt_meter_mv@cmomprd` in both; and repeat with the comma and period switched, `... = ''.,''')...`. If I'm right you'll see one of those work in both sessions. See the edited answer for more info.

Comment: @sayan - while that works, you're relying on every environment that will ever run your code having the same setting, and that may not be under your control. It's safer not to rely on NLS settings. (It would be even safer to use the correct data type, of course.. *8-)